# Kill and restart Python script every day

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitterapi-python

I have a Python code that extracts Twitter data via the streaming API. I would like to use separate files for each day so I would like to have the script running for 24 hours, then kill it and restart it as with a restart of the program the name of the file will change.

How can I ensure that the script is stopped at 00:00 and restarts right away?
The code can be found below. If you have any other ideas about how I can create a new text file daily, this would be even better.

```
import tweepy
import datetime
key_words = ["xx"]
twitter_data_title = "".join([xx, "_", date_today, ".txt"])

class TwitterStreamer():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def stream_tweets(self, twitter_data_title, key_words):
        listener = StreamListener(twitter_data_title)
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret_token)
        stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)
        stream.filter(track=key_words)


class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, twitter_data_title):
        self.fetched_tweets_filename = twitter_data_title

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print(data)
        
            with open(self.fetched_tweets_filename, 'a') as tf:
                tf.write(data)
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data %s" % str(e))
        return True
    
    def on_exception(self, exception):
        print('exception', exception)
        stream_tweets(twitter_data_title, key_words)    

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
    
def stream_tweets(twitter_data_title, key_words):
    listener = StreamListener(twitter_data_title)
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret_token)
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(track=key_words)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
    twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(twitter_data_title, key_words)
```

Comment: Python doesn't have better memory deallocation methods, so better use Shell script cronjobs to trigger and kill the python.

Comment: Use `sys.exit(0)` to exit your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the 'blocking' code in your example comes from another library, so you don't have the opportunity to (easily) change the inner loop to check for a condition and exit.

### Using a Background Process (Not Ideal)

You could change your entry point to start the code in a background process, and check to see if the file's title should have changed:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer() 
    twitter_data_title, process = None, None     

    while True:
        new_data_title = "".join([xx, "_", str(datetime.date.today()), ".txt"])

        if new_data_title == twitter_data_title:  # Nothing to do.
            sleep(60)  # Sleep for a minute
            continue  # And check again

        # Set the new title.
        twitter_data_title = new_data_title

        # If the process is already running, terminate and join it.
        if process is not None:
            process.terminate()
            process.join()

        process = Process(target=twitter_streamer.stream_tweets, args=[twitter_data_title, key_words])
        process.start()
```

### Changing `StreamListener`

A better alternative would probably be to encode the knowledge of the date into `StreamListener`. Instead of passing a file name (`twitter_data_title`), pass a file prefix (`xx` from your example), and build the filename in a property:

```py
...

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, file_prefix):
        self.prefix = file_prefix

    @property
    def fetched_tweets_filename(self):
        """The file name for the tweets."""
        date = datetime.date.today()
        return f"{self.prefix}_{date}.txt"

    ...

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
    twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(xx, key_words)
```

Since `StreamListener.on_data` grabs the file name from `self.fetched_tweets_filename`, this should mean the tweets are written to the new file when the date changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this to your code:

```
from threading import Timer

def stopTheScript():
    exec(open("anotherscript.py").read())
    exit()

Timer(86400, stopTheScript).start() #86400 s = 24 h
```